# How to add Text or image to a Excel which I read from datagrid

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am using the below code which work fine, I just want to add a customized text or image to the Excel sheet before the DataGrid data.

```
Response.Clear()

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TabelDetails.xls")

Response.Charset = ""

Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"

Dim stringWrite As StringWriter = New StringWriter()

Dim htmlWrite As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite)

Me.datagrid.RenderControl(htmlWrite)

Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString())

Response.End()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "before the datagrid data"? Do you want to display animated gif image or some "loading text..." before the data loads to the datagrid ?

Comment: Hi @coder. What i mean is now I am getting whatever in the datagrid to the excel file. i just want to add a text on rows before the datagrid data (merge, center and add text on rows before the data grid data). if i can add image to the center (on rows before my data) it will be amazing too.